# scrlttr2 - how to add the fromrule into custom-made firsthead?

Tags: koma-script, scrlttr2

Starting point should be this simple **minimum example** with the `fromrule` below the senders name and the senders personal data aligned to the right hand side:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}

\KOMAoptions { fromalign=right,
               fromrule=aftername }

\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

    \setkomavar{fromname}    {John Doe (sender)}
    \setkomavar{fromaddress} {25th Doe's Avenue \\ 54321 Springfield}

\begin{letter}  { Maria Lae\\
                  2th Coast Road\\
                  12345 Milltown }

        \opening{Dear Maria,}

            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
            nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
            erat, sed diam voluptua.

        \closing{Sincerely yours}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, both the `fromrule` and the set alignment disappear by use of a custom-made `firsthead` despite of performed activation by setting `fromrule=aftername` and `fromalign=right` in the preamble.

The only way to preserve `fromrule` and alignment is to remove the custom-made `firsthead` out of the source code.

How can I add the `fromrule` into a custom `firsthead`, for example inside this self made exemplary `firsthead`-code like the following:

```
\setkomavar{firsthead} {%
             {\usekomafont{fromname}\strut\ignorespaces\usekomavar{fromname}} \\
             {\usekomafont{fromaddress}\strut\ignorespaces\usekomavar{fromaddress}}
            }
```

**Of course, I also could easily add an ordinary line by inserting...**

```
\rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
```

**... at the final desired position** (below the senders name) ...

```
\setkomavar{firsthead} {%
             {\usekomafont{fromname}\strut\ignorespaces\usekomavar{fromname}} \\
             \rule{\textwidth}{.5pt}
             {\usekomafont{fromaddress}\strut\ignorespaces\usekomavar{fromaddress}}
            }
```

... , but ordinary lines use completely different spaces and distances to the text than the `fromrule`. That's the reason why I want to continue to to use the `fromrule` instead of an ordinary one...

Do you have any ideas? Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to use the `fromrule` option together with `firsthead`. But here is an suggestion how you can get the same line as in your MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
%\KOMAoptions { fromalign=right,
               %fromrule=aftername }

\setkomavar{firsthead}{%
  \parbox{\textwidth}{
  \raggedleft
  {\usekomafont{fromname}\strut\ignorespaces\usekomavar{fromname}} \\[-.5\baselineskip]
  {\usekomafont{fromrule}\rule{\textwidth}{\useplength{fromrulethickness}}}\\
  {\usekomafont{fromaddress}\strut\ignorespaces\usekomavar{fromaddress}}
  }}

\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}    {John Doe (sender)}
\setkomavar{fromaddress} {25th Doe's Avenue \\ 54321 Springfield}

\begin{letter}{Maria Lae\\
               2th Coast Road\\
               12345 Milltown}

  \opening{Dear Maria,}

  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
  nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam
  erat, sed diam voluptua.

  \closing{Sincerely yours}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "It is not possible to use the fromrule option together with firsthead." Okay, I didn't know that for sure... Thank you very much!